# How can I beautifully deal with this dirty-multiple-try code

Tags: python, try-catch, except

Hi guys please help me to revise this code.
You probably know what I'm trying to do
It isn't critical to have keyError but anyway I want to try every del code.
It works as I intended, but I'm pretty sure there is more beautiful way to do this.

```
try:
    del response_json['sha1']
except:
    print("keyError: Fail to delete sha1 hash key")
try:
    del response_json['sha224']
except:
    print("keyError: Fail to delete sha224 hash key")
try:
    del response_json['sha256']
except:
    print("keyError: Fail to delete sha256 hash key")
try:
    del response_json['sha384']
except:
    print("keyError: Fail to delete sha384 hash key")
try:
    del response_json['sha512']
except:
    print("keyError: Fail to delete sha512 hash key")
```

I can do this as below but this way if first del code raise error, then the rest of code will not be executed, right?

```
try:
    del response_json['sha1']
    del response_json['sha224']
    del response_json['sha256']
    del response_json['sha384']
    del response_json['sha512']
except:
    print("keyError: Fail to delete hash key")
```

Thank you for reading this

Comment: What happens when you run the code under the failure condition you're asking about.  Don't ask *us* if something will work -- *try* it.  Until you can demonstrate a definite problem, you do not have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to ask a question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop to iterate the values

```
lst = ['sha1','sha224','sha256','sha384','sha512']
for s in lst:
    try:
        del response_json[s]
    except:
        print(f"keyError: Fail to delete {s} hash key")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think response_json is a dictionary and not just a list.
I think you need something that is more dynamic and adaptable to all situations. Just populate the keys and delete each key-value pair one after the other.
This solution goes for any length and any dictionary you might encounter in the future.

```
json_keys = [ key for key in response_json]
for keys in json_keys:
    try:
        del response_json[keys]
    except:
        print(f"keyError: Fail to delete hash key")
```

Comment: this code deletes every keys in response_json, right? Then it's not what I wanted but thank you for replying my question.